# i am using laravel 5.4 and from submission using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

**laravel form code**

```
 @foreach($products as $product) <form action="{{ url('/cart/add') }}" method="post">
                      {{ csrf_field() }}
                      <input type="text" name="img" value="{!! $product->product_image !!}" id="img{!! $product->product_image !!}">
                      <input type="text" name="price" value="{!! $product->product_price !!}" id="price{!! $product->product_price !!}">
                      <input type="text" name="name" value="{!! $product->product_name !!}" id="pro_name{!! $product->product_name !!}">
                      <input type="text" name="id" value="{!! $product->id !!}" id="pro_id{!! $product->id !!}"><br>
                      <!--<input id="form-control" type="number" max="10" min="1" class="form-control" name="qty" value="1">-->
                      <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">
                        <select class="select_val" id="form-control{!! $product->id !!}" name="qty" >
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                          <option value="4">4</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>
                          <option value="6">6</option>
                          <option value="7">7</option>
                          <option value="8">8</option>
                          <option value="9">9</option>
                          <option value="10">10</option> 
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addtocart<?php echo $product->id ?>">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> &nbsp;Add-to-cart
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
     @endforeach
```

***javascript code***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 @foreach($products as $product) 

      jQuery('#addtocart{!! $product->id !!}').on('click',function(e){

            $.ajaxSetup({
                         headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 
                         $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
            });

            e.preventDefault();

        var  pro_name  = $('#pro_name{!! $product->product_name !!}').val();

        var  id   = $('#form-control{!! $product->id !!}').val(); 

        var  image  = $('#img{!! $product->product_image !!}').val();

        var  price  = $('#price{!! $product->product_price !!}').val();

         alert("qty-"+id+"-"+pro_name+"-"+"-"+image+"-"+price);
```

jQuery.ajax({
                    url:'{{ url("/cart/add") }} ',
                    method: 'post',
                    data : {
                  token :token,
                        name: pro_name,
                        quantity : qty,
                        img : image,
                        price : price
                    },
                    success  : function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                }

```
        });         

      }); 
    @endforeach   
 });`
```

[its my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuakC.png)

[another image is alert box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcqhP.png)

```
i am not getting proper value price and image name in alert box
```

***i am using laravel 5.4 and from submission using ajax***

***how to get rid of this errors***

Answer (score 0):

get read of the loop, get the inputs relative to your form

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      jQuery('[id^="addtocart"]').on('click',function(e){

            $.ajaxSetup({
                         headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 
                         $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
            });

            e.preventDefault();

        var  pro_name  = $(this).closest('form').find('[id^="pro_name"]').val();

        var  qty =  $(this).closest('form').find('[id^="form-control"]').val(); 

        var  image  =  $(this).closest('form').find('[id^="img"]').val();

        var  price  =  $(this).closest('form').find('[id^="price"]').val();

         alert("qty-"+qty+"-"+pro_name+"-"+"-"+image+"-"+price);

      });  
 });`
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176895/discussion-on-answer-by-madalinivascu-i-am-using-laravel-5-4-and-from-submission).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do could work with many bug fixes, but it is no longer in the sense of decent source code.
Work in JS with a function that passes the product ID and continue working with it. 
The IDs of your input elements are nonsense. You cannot put an image in an ID field

```
id="img{!! $product->product_image !!}"
```

Do it like this

```
id="img-{!! $product->id !!}"
```

---

**UPDATE**

Your button need to execute a JS function

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToCart({!! $product->id !!})">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> &nbsp;Add-to-cart
 </button>
```

Create a function called addToCart(productId)

```
function addToCart(productId) {
  let name = $('#img-' + productId).val();
  let price = $('#price-' + productId).val();
  alert('Image Name: ' + name + ', Price: ' + price);
}
```

Now the ID of the product is transferred when the button is pressed. In JS, you search for the required values using a "naming convention + ID" (example: id="img-PRODUCTID" / id="price-PRODUCTID").

With jQuery you can then retrieve the necessary values

let elementValue = $('#ELEMENT-PRODUCT-ID').val();

Comment: then how to get image name and price in jquery variable .

Comment: let price = $('#price-' + productId).val();   unable to understand and

Comment: Take a look at the docs: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: could u help to get rid of this puzzle

Comment: This would be a Ajax call error. Check the response Body